# Override Wordpress plugin jQuery settings

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm sure I am overlooking something as it seems simple...but I can't seem to override a plugin jQuery.

For example the plugin is using pickatime as follows...

```
$( '.timepicker' ).pickatime({
        interval: 15
    });
```

but I want to change that to 'interval: 30'...how can I override that?

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough details. But where you should start is dequeue_script for the plugin script, and then enqueue your own script in your theme/child theme.

Comment: I did look into the dequeue_script route but I need some of the original script intact.  I just need to change the interval.  There must be a way to augment the original script?

Comment: That is unlikely . Copy all of the script to your own file. Make the Change... dequeue the old one. Enqueue the new one. I believe javascript hooks only exist within Gutenberg blocks.

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough details.